# Как проверить, является ли массив чисел подмножеством разделённых запятыми чисел в строке?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь проверить, является ли массив чисел подмножеством разделённых запятыми чисел в строке.

Например, я хочу получить `ID` записей в таблице:

| ID | STRING1 | STRING2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100,101,201 | 1,2,3,4 |
| 2 | 100,103,201,202 | 1,4,9,10 |
| 3 | 101,102,200 | 1,3,4 |

которые удовлетворяют условию (псевдокод):

```
(100,201) is subset of STRING1 AND (1,4) is subset of STRING2
```

Ожидаемый результат: ID 1 и 2

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to find numbers inside selected string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69195894) от участника [@maxime mkhe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16920124/maxime-mkhe)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69195894

Answer (score 3):

Вот один из способов, организовать все для более легкгой поддержки. Предполагаю, что версия 12.1 или выше, поэтому можно использовать функции JSON (для удобной работы по разделению списков). В более старых версиях придется написать функцию по-другому, но концепция будет той же.

Идея заключается в том, чтобы написать функцию, которая разбивает списки чисел и возвращает вместо них вложенную таблицу. Потребуется глобальный тип данных (на уровне схемы).

Подготовка схемы:

```
create or replace type tbl_of_num is table of number;
/
create or replace function str_to_tbl(s varchar2) return tbl_of_num deterministic is
    pragma udf;
    ton tbl_of_num;
begin
    select cast(collect(val) as tbl_of_num) into ton
    from json_table('[' || s || ']', '$[*]' columns val number path '$');
    return ton;
end;
/
create table t (id, string1, string2) as
    select 1, '100,101,201', '1,2,3,4'  from dual union all
    select 2, '100,103,201', '1,4,9,10' from dual union all
    select 3, '101,102,200', '1,3,4,10' from dual;
```

Сначала определяю две переменные связывания, инициализирую их и использую в запросе:

```
variable string1 varchar2(100)
variable string2 varchar2(100)

exec :string1 := '100,201'; :string2 := '1,4'

select id
from   t
where str_to_tbl(:string1) submultiset of str_to_tbl(string1)
  and str_to_tbl(:string2) submultiset of str_to_tbl(string2);

        ID
----------
         1
         2
```

Возможны другие способы передачи значений в переменных связывания, это зависит от приложения.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198330) от участника [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Ешё два пути решения задачи без создания дополнительных обьектов БД.

Для удобства создал только одну вложенную таблиицу `numtab`, но если и это нежелательно, для непривилегированных пользователей доступнa `mdsys.sdo_numtab`.

Наиболее эффективно, с обявлением функции в запросе:

```
with 
function toNumTab (str varchar2) return numtab is
    pos int := 1; len int := 0; 
    r numtab := numtab ();
begin <<split>> loop
        len := instr (str||',', ',', pos);
        exit split when len = 0;
        r.extend; r(r.last) := to_number (substr (str, pos, len-pos));
        pos := len+1; 
    end loop;
    return r;
end;
args (arg1, arg2) as (
    select numtab (100, 201), numtab (1, 4) 
    from dual 
)  
select id
from t, args
where args.arg1 submultiset of toNumTab (string1) and
      args.arg2 submultiset of toNumTab (string2);
```

На чистом SQL можно расспарсить список чисел из строки стандартной функцией `XMLTable`, но в этом случае, надо будет ее результат сначало конвертировать во вложеную таблицу, чтобы воспользоваться фунццией `submultiset`:

```
with 
t1 (id, nt1, nt2) as (
    select id, 
        (select cast (collect (to_number (column_value)) as numtab) from xmlTable (string1)),
        (select cast (collect (to_number (column_value)) as numtab) from xmlTable (string2))
    from t
    ),
args (arg1, arg2) as (
    select numtab (100, 201), numtab (1, 4)
    from dual 
)  
select id
from t1, args
where arg1 submultiset of t1.nt1 and
      arg2 submultiset of t1.nt2
```

Оба запроса выше вернут ожидаемый результат (см. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c30d8fcace7330fb945db0918b51ea10)).